# Convert A POSIXt Time To A Julian Day

Tags: r, date, transform, posixct

I was looking for someway to transform a date in POSIXct format to Julian day
_
The Julian Day Number (JDN) is the integer assigned to a whole solar day in the Julian day count starting from noon Universal time, with Julian day number 0 assigned to the day starting at noon on Monday, January 1, 4713 BC, proleptic Julian calendar (November 24, 4714 BC, in the proleptic Gregorian calendar)
_

But I just figured out how to make a year day - 1 to 365 for leap year.
Could someone help me find some function that turns POSIXct dates (like: 2010-10-02 21:00:00) into Julian dates?

I have a column on a dataframe with several dates to be transformed into Julian days.

```
head(head(all_jub2$timestamp_adjusted)
[1] 2010-10-02 21:00:00 2010-10-03 03:00:00 2010-10-03 09:00:00 2010-10-03 15:00:00
[5] 2010-10-03 21:00:00 2010-10-04 03:00:00
6120 Levels: 2003-10-17 21:00:00 2003-10-18 03:00:00 ... 2020-01-10 09:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with base R *provided you start at the right point*. The text in your question your data is still a `factor`-type variable. That is not good -- you need to parse this, and for example the `anytime()` function of the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package can help you.  See other questions here on that.

Back to the question. If you start with a `POSIXct` variable from current time, and for argument's sake an hour ago to have vector, we can a) convert it to `Date` and then b) from `Date` to a Julian:

```
R> input <- Sys.time() + c(-3600,0)
R> input
[1] "2020-09-29 13:07:50.225898 CDT" "2020-09-29 14:07:50.225898 CDT"
R> as.Date(input)
[1] "2020-09-29" "2020-09-29"
R> julian(as.Date(input))
[1] 18534 18534
attr(,"origin")
[1] "1970-01-01"
R>
```

So for today our Julian date is 18534. For your first two data points, we get 14884 and 14885.

```
R> input <- c("2010-10-02 21:00:00", "2010-10-03 03:00:00")
R> anytime::anydate(input)
[1] "2010-10-02" "2010-10-03"
R> julian(anytime::anydate(input))
[1] 14884 14885
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "America/Chicago"
attr(,"origin")
[1] "1970-01-01"
R>
```

If you only want to day of the year, you get that as the component `yday` of the `POSIXlt` representation *but you need to adjust by one* as it is zero based:

```
R> as.POSIXlt(anytime::anytime(input))$yday + 1
[1] 275 276
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package makes it easy to deal with dates. Does this solve your issue?

```
library(lubridate)

date <- as.POSIXct('2010-10-02 21:00:00')

julian <- yday(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but i foun what i've been looking for using the package `insol`

```
library(insol)

julian_day <- insol::JD(as.POSIXct('2010-10-02 21:00:00'))
[1] 2455473
```